# Proguard check using command line on android apk?

Tags: android, command-line, proguard

Is there any way to check if `apk` is `proguard` protected without de-complying it?

For example, using some command or any other similar way.

Comment: As I know proguard is a compile time utility. This means that it doesn't store any files in final apk. It only exclude unused resources and rename classes, variables and some other resources, some times with including one classes into others. Final apk is just an archive. Open it with any archive utility, then extract .class file and open it in any text editor. If you couldn't understand any of word in it, for example, method name can look like "aaaaaa(String kkkk)" then it means that this apk was compiled with hello of proguard.